# Determine speed of moving vehicle from video taken in a moving vehicle

Tags: velocity, speed, data-analysis

I have dash camera footage from my motorcycle where the police were speeding illegally in dangerous conditions. I know my speedo is 7% over so if it reads 107KPH a radar gun will ping me at 100KPH.

I matched their speed just long enough to determine the reading and deducted 7% and found they were doing 124KPH in a 100KPH zone in storm weather that preceded catastrophic flooding. The penalty for this is $170 and 35 license demerits and there were two of them.

Because I don't and can't have a radar gun I need to show on the video what their speed was to have any shred of evidence against them. Forgive me if this makes it political but in my country the police are very very abusive and if I report them they will not be penalized whatsoever, instead I need to send the evidence to courts; I feel the need to do something.

My dash camera doesn't have GPS so I can't use my own speed in the calculation :(

Is there a formula that can reasonably show at least a "good enough" approximation of their speed? Especially since they weren't moving laterally past a static camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go back to the road where you filmed them speeding, and measure accurately the physical distance between two landmarks. For example, from one telegraph pole to another.

View the footage on your camera and notice the amount of time it takes the car to move between the two landmarks. The speed they travelled will be this distance divided by the time, or $$\text{speed}=\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}}$$

Note that you ideally would like two landmarks that are a fair distance, to minimize error, and to also ensure that the vehicles were not changing speed during the interval.

I am not sure the evidentiary value of this, though, nor do I think it will accepted as evidence unless you are an expert in the field eg., an engineer or physicist.

- Note that if you measured the distance in meters and time in seconds, then you need to convert whatever speed you got in $m/s$ to $km/hr$ and to do tis you multiply what you got by $3.6$
- You will need to take into account sources of possible error, so that after you do an error analysis, you will get an answer that will look like eg., $(124 \pm 3) \ km/hr$.

Comment: Thank you! This seems like a solid lead. I'll leave it open a little while longer to leave time for alternative answers before marking it as correct. I am not a physicist or engineer but I am a game developer so I can create simulations by recreating the scenario and show videos of what it looks like at different speeds, and then set the simulation to run at the speed the officers were going and show that it lines up with the dash camera footage.

Comment: Sure. No problems. Hopefully whoever sees your analysis has some knowledge in physics. good luck!